# Firefox sync cookies

Tags: firefox, cookies, firefox-sync

I went a bit paranoid recently, and I disabled all cookies in Firefox. I'm manually allowing them for sites that I find worthy.

Then I decided to sync my bookmarks to the Firefox on my phone. (Yeah.) Even though I enabled cookies manually for `about:accounts`, Firefox still says that

> Cookies and local storage are required.
>
> Cookies are still disabled

The question would be: for what site would I need to grant cookie rights for Firefox sync being able to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really answer the part about which site's cookies do I need, but apparently signing in to Firefox sync works with the settings described above, only signing up doesn't. Therefore the only thing I needed was to register in another browser without the cookie restrictions (which is the case on my phone as I can't manage cookies one by one there), and then sign in to Firefox sync on my desktop, and it just worked.

Comment: I think there is a different issue since the problem arises at sign-in for a bunch of different people: https://github.com/mozilla/fxa-content-server/issues/4796 and https://github.com/mozilla/fxa-content-server/issues/4778

Comment: Definitely a different issue, my problem was already there in December, these Github issues seem to be quite new.